# Access VBA visible control form from another form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have a table and form setup to control another form in my database.
I'm wanting to make a code that will take the title from my field and add it to my code as a variable to change the visibility options of my other form.

my form is set with all the of the names to all objects on the form I want to control.

LSE_FORM_ADMIN = The table with all the LSE_FORM_ALL names in it.
Table is setup with 3 columns key, names and a checkbox which I put into a form to make a continuous list.

here is my code on the form, but I keep getting and runtime 424: object required error:

```
    Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim VARSET As Object
    Dim VAR As String
    VARSET = DLookup("TITLE", Table!LSE_FORM_ADMIN, "") 'keep getting error here
    VAR = VARSET
    If Me!CB = "-1" Then
    Form_LSE_FORM_ALL!VAR.Visible = True
    Else
    Form_LSE_FORM_ALL!VAR.Visible = False
    End If
    End Sub
```

can someone help me fix this code so that it will grab the title field data and make it a variable to add to the rest of the code?

Comment: The second field of your DLOOKUP is incorrect. You are supposed to provide the table name or query name. Use the following including quotes: "LSE_FORM_ADMIN". That will get you further, but then it will crash again because of VARSET not being referenced/used/set properly. You mention "names of all objects...to control", but your code will not return all records. You will need to open a recordset then loop thru all rows.

Comment: took what you said and tried to make a record set, though Im not sure if that is what i need. all titles are in a subform anyways, so focus should give me the correct title if I can get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to see exactly what you are trying to achieve, but your problems stem from using the variant variable type when you should be using an explicit Form or Control type. Using your last example.

> RSTT.Visible = True    'getting Run-time error '424': object required

This is because you have declared RSTT as a variant. The line

```
RSTT = "Form_LSE_FORM_ALL" & "!" & (RST)
```

results in the variable RSTT containing a string, which does not have a property ".Visible"

> ```
> Set DB = CurrentDb
> Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("LSE_FORM_ADMIN")
> ```

These lines are redundant as you have the values that you need available on the form fields which are already bound to the table LSE_FORM_ADMIN.

As far as I understand, you have a continuous form (ADMIN?) bound to the table LSE_FORM_Admin. As you step through the records on this form, you want code to be fired which takes the value of the TITLE field/control and use it to set a control with the same name, on a separate form, Form_LSE_FORM_ALL, to be (in)visible, dependent on the value of the checkbox control name CB on the ADMIN form?

If you want the ADMIN form to make the changes "live" to the ALL form, you should consider using an event of the CB checkbox control. Using the current event of the form means that the changes you make will not be reflected in the ALL form until you step out of the record you have just edited, then back in, to fire the form's Current event on that record.

Example using AfterUpdate event of CB checkbox

```
Private Sub CB_AfterUpdate()

Dim strRST As String
Dim frmTarget as Form
Dim ctlRSTT As Control

Set strRST = Me!TITLE
Set frmTarget = Forms("Form_LSE_FORM_ALL")
Set ctlRSTT = frmTarget.Controls(strRST)

ctlRSTT.Visible = Me!CB    'getting Run-time error '424': object required

End Sub
```

Comment: That did it, just had to change a few things to get a few bugs out but perfect works like a dream and my form control panel works fantastic. thank you for your help! ill post the final code in the following answer.

Comment: You're welcome Josiah...Good catch on the string variable. Any variable with rst or rs to me is typically a recordset, hence the mistake. No excuse.......but an explanation . You would probably find it useful to read an article on variable naming conventions. Using standard rules can help a lot when it comes to readability and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

really not sure how to do the syntax when doing a recordset to a table from the form, need some help with that.
here is my code and attempt at the record set:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim DB As Database
Dim RS As Recordset
Dim RST As String

    Set DB = CurrentDb
    Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("LSE_FORM_ADMIN")
    Set RST = RS              'GETTING OBJECT REQUIRED ERROR ON "RST ="

    Do Until RS.EOF
        RST = Me!TITLE
        RS.MoveNext
    Loop

If Me!CB = "-1" Then
Form_LSE_FORM_ALL!RS.Visible = True
Else
Form_LSE_FORM_ALL!RS.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but I only have my Droid right now. Your code needs to open a record set (query or table)... your code doesn't reference either.  I will have my laptop tomorrow and can post code for you..

Comment: thanks for the hint, the syntax on the recordset is a bit confusing to me, i should really find a guy to teach this to me so i can understand how it works, I get the jist is to make a set of data that will be like a usable table for the code to apply to the variable i set it as. but doesn't seem to be working that way just yet.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I know what you are trying to do, but your descriptions / references are not matching up. Please look at the following comments and clarify:
1. You say "...make a code that will take the title from my field and ..." but your code is taking "Me.Title", "ME" is a reference to the Form - not a field.
2. Your code is in the "Form_Current" event, which means it will fire for every record you process. That will work, but I think you want to do this code only once to be more efficient.
3. You have no provision for processing more than one field. I think you need to loop through all fields in your table, setting visible to true or false.

The following is my suggestion, but I will update once you clarify the issues.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim DB      As DAO.Database
Dim RS      As DAO.Recordset
'Dim RST     As Variant
'Dim RSTT    As Variant

 Public Sub FORM_CURRENT()

 Set DB = CurrentDb
 Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("LSE_FORM_ADMIN")
 Do While Not RS.EOF                    ' Loop thru all field names for the form
    If RS!HideYN = True Then            ' Desire to hide the field?
        Me(RS!ctlname).Visible = False   ' Yes, hide the field.
    Else
        Me(RS!ctlname).Visible = True    ' No, show the field
    End If

    RS.MoveNext                         ' Get next field name
 Loop
 RS.Close
 Set RS = Nothing
 Set DB = Nothing
 'Set RST = Me!Title
 'RSTT = "Form_LSE_FORM_ALL" & "!" & (RST)

'If Me!CB = "-1" Then
'    RSTT.Visible = True    'getting Run-time error '424': object required
'Else
'    RSTT.Visible = False
'End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner. in short I'm making a form to dictate my other forms like a control panel.  Reason for doing this is I deal with other job sites so im not always around and I wanted an easier way for another "lesser access skilled" person to be able to change my form to the needs of the project. also for ease of access form for my boss to just check boxes instead of send me huge lists of fields in emails. now I just give her this and she just checks what she needs and load it up and done! so if you would like to see how it works together let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Final code, thanks to Cheesenbranston.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
Dim strRST As String
Dim frmTarget As Form
Dim ctlRSTT As Control

strRST = Me!TITLE
Set frmTarget = Forms("LSE_FORM_ALL")
Set ctlRSTT = frmTarget.Controls(strRST)

    If Me!CB = "-1" Then
        ctlRSTT.Visible = True
        Else
        ctlRSTT.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

@Cheesenbranston: Your original code was more like a toggle of on and off so if my object was not visible then my trigger checkbox would make it visible when checked, more of a quality of life for my own needs, none the less worked.  Also strRST doesn't need SET since its just a String. Thanks again =D very happy day!